# Removing additional spaces in a table <td>

Tags: css

I have some spaces around each and every `<td>` in the question palette. Hereby I have attached the screenshot.[image: Problem]

Comment: Could you provide your codes and css?

Comment: td, th {
    border: 1px solid #d8dcdd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 10px

Comment: Please remove padding like `padding: none;`.

Comment: @AdhiyanChandrasekaran Can you update your post directly with all relevant information?

Answer (score 0):

Padding is the reason that there are unexpected spaces in each td and th.
So you need to remove them.

```
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #d8dcdd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: none;
}
```

And I am not sure but, it seems like the border is useless in your picture.
So remove it also.

```
td, th {
  border: none;
  padding: none;
}
```